# Converter pagina html para jsf

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

Bom baixei um template que será a index do meu projeto, entao ja esta tudo configurado o `web.xhtml`, já rodo outros projetos jsf, porem estou iniciando outro projeto e quero colocar um template que peguei em html5 para rodar como index, porem queria saber como adaptar ela para rodar, bom veja o codigo da pagina:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Moviereviews - Free CSS template by ChocoTemplates.com</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css/images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<!-- wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="light-bg">
        <!-- shell -->
        <div class="shell">
            <!-- header -->
            <div class="header">
                <!-- socials -->
                <div class="socials">
                    <a href="#" class="facebook-ico">facebook-ico</a>
                    <a href="#" class="twitter-ico">twitter-ico</a>
                    <a href="#" class="you-tube-ico">you-tube-ico</a>
                </div>
                <!-- end of socials -->
                <h1 id="logo"><a href="#">Moviereviews</a></h1>
                <!-- navigation -->
                <nav id="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SHOW ALL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">LATEST MOVIES <span>20</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">TOP RATED</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MOST COMMENTED</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- end of navigation -->
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of header -->
            <!-- main -->
            <div class="main">
                <!-- content -->
                <section class="content">
                    <!-- post -->
                    <div class="post">
                        <!-- post-inner -->
                        <div class="post-inner">
                            <header>
                                <h2><a href="#">MovieTitle 1 Goes Here</a></h2>
                                <p class="tags"><a href="#">FAMILY</a> <a href="#">COMEDY</a> <a href="#">ANIMATION</a> </p>
                                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                            </header>
                            <div class="img-holder">
                                <a href="#"><img src="css/images/post-img.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                <a href="css/images/post-img.jpg" class="btn-full-image popup"><span>FULL IMAGE</span></a>
                            </div>

                            <!-- meta -->
                            <div class="meta">
                                <p class="date">APRIL 09, 2012 by <a href="#">JOHN DOE</a></p>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="rating-holder">
                                        <p>RATING</p>
                                        <div class="rating">
                                            <span style="width: 100%;"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#" class="comments">59 comments</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of meta -->
                            <!-- post-cnt -->
                            <div class="post-cnt">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut commodo orci vitae enim volutpat dapibus. Aliquam pharetra, odio eu luctus semper, dolor libero volutpat mi, sit amet convallis tortor justo eu nisl. Cras quis felis quis felis tempor volutpat id at dui. Donec vel turpis id odio tempus mollis quis vel justo. Etiam tortor nisi, pulvinar a mattis nec, luctus sit amet odio. Morbi id commodo ligula. </p>
                                <a href="#" class="more">CONTINUE READING</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of post-cnt -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- post-inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                    <!-- post -->
                    <div class="post">
                        <!-- post-inner -->
                        <div class="post-inner">
                            <header>
                                <h2><a href="#">MovieTitle 2 Goes Here</a></h2>
                                <p class="tags"><a href="#">FAMILY</a> <a href="#">COMEDY</a> <a href="#">ANIMATION</a> </p>
                                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                            </header>
                            <div class="img-holder">
                                <a href="#"><img src="css/images/post-img2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                <a href="css/images/post-img2.jpg" class="btn-full-image popup"><span>FULL IMAGE</span></a>
                            </div>

                            <!-- meta -->
                            <div class="meta">
                                <p class="date">APRIL 09, 2012 by <a href="#">JOHN DOE</a></p>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="rating-holder">
                                        <p>RATING</p>
                                        <div class="rating">
                                            <span style="width: 50%;"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#" class="comments">59 comments</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of meta -->
                            <!-- post-cnt -->
                            <div class="post-cnt">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut commodo orci vitae enim volutpat dapibus. Aliquam pharetra, odio eu luctus semper, dolor libero volutpat mi, sit amet convallis tortor justo eu nisl. Cras quis felis quis felis tempor volutpat id at dui. Donec vel turpis id odio tempus mollis quis vel justo. Etiam tortor nisi, pulvinar a mattis nec, luctus sit amet odio. Morbi id commodo ligula. </p>
                                <a href="#" class="more">CONTINUE READING</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of post-cnt -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- post-inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                    <!-- post -->
                    <div class="post">
                        <!-- post-inner -->
                        <div class="post-inner">
                            <header>
                                <h2><a href="#">MovieTitle 3 Goes Here</a></h2>
                                <p class="tags"><a href="#">FAMILY</a> <a href="#">COMEDY</a> <a href="#">ANIMATION</a> </p>
                                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                            </header>
                            <div class="img-holder">
                                <a href="#"><img src="css/images/post-img3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                <a href="css/images/post-img3.jpg" class="btn-full-image popup"><span>FULL IMAGE</span></a>
                            </div>

                            <!-- meta -->
                            <div class="meta">
                                <p class="date">APRIL 09, 2012 by <a href="#">JOHN DOE</a></p>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="rating-holder">
                                        <p>RATING</p>
                                        <div class="rating">
                                            <span style="width: 70%;"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#" class="comments">59 comments</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of meta -->
                            <!-- post-cnt -->
                            <div class="post-cnt">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut commodo orci vitae enim volutpat dapibus. Aliquam pharetra, odio eu luctus semper, dolor libero volutpat mi, sit amet convallis tortor justo eu nisl. Cras quis felis quis felis tempor volutpat id at dui. Donec vel turpis id odio tempus mollis quis vel justo. Etiam tortor nisi, pulvinar a mattis nec, luctus sit amet odio. Morbi id commodo ligula. </p>
                                <a href="#" class="more">CONTINUE READING</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of post-cnt -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- post-inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                    <div class="pagination">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="laquo"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                            <li class="raquo"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
                            <li class="dots">. . .</li>
                            <li><a href="#">last</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <!-- end of content -->
                <!-- sidebar -->
                <aside class="sidebar">
                    <div class="widget">
                        <h3 class="widgettitle">Genres</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Comedy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Family</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mystery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sci-Fi</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">War</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Western</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Adventure</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Crime</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fantasy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Horror</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Thriller</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="widget">
                        <h3 class="widgettitle">Opening This Week</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">The Hunter Games <strong>$98 Mil</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">American Reunion <strong>$50 Mil</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Titanic <strong>$23 Mil</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Wrath of the Titans <strong>$50 Mil</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mirror Mirro  <strong>$7 Mil</strong></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="widget socials-widget">
                        <h3 class="widgettitle">Get Connected</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" class="facebook-ico"><span></span>Facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="twitter-ico"><span></span>Twitter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="linkedin-ico"><span></span>Linkedin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="you-tube-ico"><span></span>Youtube</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="rss-ico"><span></span>RSS</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </aside>
                <!-- end of sidebar -->
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of main -->
            <div class="footer">
                <nav class="footer-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Show All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Latest Movies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Top Rated</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Most Commented</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <p class="copy">Copyright &copy; 2012 <span>|</span> Sitename. Design by <a href="http://chocotemplates.com" target="_blank">ChocoTemplates.com</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of shell -->
    </div>  
</div>
<!-- end of wrapper -->
```

porem da erro:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing
>   /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 49] A entidade "nbsp" foi
>   referenciada, mas não declarada.

Quais são as alterações que preciso fazer para rodar no jsf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tá bem claro:

`<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>`

troca esse trecho por:

`<div class="cl"><h:outputText value=" " /></div>`

Investigar erros com mais empenho antes de procurar ajuda pode te salvar tempo. ;)

Comment: Obrigado funcionou!

Comment: mobg eu acho que deve haver outras maneiras de reconhecer entidaddes html